# Angular get UrlSegment from ActiveRouteSnapshot

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I need to get UrlSegment from `Route` I `console.log` and the output is attached in SS.

```
canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
     console.log(childRoute)
}
```

I want to get `segments` Array inside `_urlSegment` how to achieve this any help?

P.S: All keys starting with `_` are private is there any other way to get the desired result i.e `segments Array`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to get `_urlSegments` there is an other parameter `state` in `canActivateChild()` method which returns current complete URL which we can parse and get segments here is the example:

```
canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
     const tree = this.router.parseUrl(state.url);
     const children = tree.root.children[PRIMARY_OUTLET];
     const segments = children.segments;
     console.log(segments[1].path); //which is 'orientation' - see above SS
}
```

For reference [visit](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSegment).